# GUI Debugging server app using Visual Studio Code

Tags: 16.04, c++, visual-studio-code

I've been tasked with getting a GUI Debugger working for project being developed for Ubuntu 16.04 server in C++ 11.0 with BOOST.

I've got the app building and running on 'headless' Ubuntu 16.04 servers.  My boss is a windows user and wants me to set the build so that he can connect via his windows computer, and use Visual Studio Code on the server to debug the program.  I think he put it like this: "just setup X11 or some XWindows server so my box can code/debug the app."

I've gotten an x11 service up and running, and loaded up firefox in this environment, but it was painfully slow. Basically followed:

http://dasunhegoda.com/gui-ubuntu-server-x11-forwarding/679/.

Is this possible?  I desperately need suggestions, and no he doesn't want to use an Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop like I'm doing.

Comment: It's a bit of a game of chinese whispers here, but it sounds like what your boss has in mind is something like PuTTY + xming, or MobaXterm (a Windows SSH client with a built-in X server).

Comment: Mobaxterm did the trick.  Now I have to see if I can get it all working on a Docker container.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you @steeldriver, MobaXTerm worked beautifully.  It's working now, but took a bit to get Visual Studio Code for linux up and working!  Once I got all the dependancies all worked out it ran pretty well on my iMac.  Can't say the same for my Windows computer, it was still a little glitchy in the window update department, but worked like I needed anyway.